# How to export a declared external value as a named export?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Exporting a declared value (i.e. an assumed externally-defined global variable) as a default export [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPCgK4C2ARiDALABQIAHgA5IxajZTERa5JA) as expected:

```
// TypeScript
declare const foo: number
export default foo

// ES2015
export default foo;
```

But trying to export it as a named export [does not](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDsiA7AZ3gDMIIAuOPAVwFsAjYKIA):

```
// TypeScript
export declare const foo: number

// ES2015
export {};
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Does changing the top example to `export default {foo}` work?

Comment: You can try it out yourself on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPCgK4C2ARiDALABQIAHgA5IxajZTERYDeuSAL5A). Yes, that does work. This solution is a little disappointing because I'm trying to compile someone else's source file, and having to modify the source is a step too far, but maybe this is the best that can be done for now. Is it reasonable to expect my second example to work the same way? Is this a shortcoming in the compiler?

Comment: If that's a `d.ts` file accompying some `js` file you don't have to use `declare`. `export const foo: number` is sufficient.

Comment: `.d.ts` alone is insufficient. This needs to compile to an ES2015 module because I'm using it with Rollup. I need a `.ts` module that essentially exports an object filled with global variables.

Comment: I created a typescript issue on this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54848 however it seems this is somehow working as intended???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
declare global {
    var foo: number;
}
export const foo = globalThis.foo;
```

This declares that there is a global `var`iable named `foo` (created by some other code), then creates a local `const` named `foo` which is initialised with the global value and exports it under the name `foo`.

If using `globalThis` does not work for you (e.g. because the global is actually declared as a `const`, not a property of the global object like a `var` would be), then you need to introduce a local identifier with a different name to avoid collisions and export that:

```
declare global {
    const foo: number;
}
const _foo = foo;
export { _foo as foo }
```

This declares that there is a global `const`ant named `foo` (created by some other script), then creates a local `const` named `_foo` which is initialised with the global value and exports it under the name `foo`.

This is pretty much exactly what your default export does as well - `export default foo;` is equivalent to

```
const _default = foo;
export { _default as default }
```

(except `_default` is a hidden binding that cannot be accessed from code).

It is not possible in ECMAScript modules to `export` a variable that is neither declared by the current module itself nor exported by some other module (which you could `export { … } from '…';`). Every exported binding must be declared in a module.